# pytest won't convert date field to datetime.date object in Django

Tags: python, django, pytest

I have this simple query written in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and I want to run my tests with [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/).

```
results = (self.base_query
                   .order_by('service_date')
                   .extra({'sd': "date(service_date)"})
                   .values('sd')
                   .annotate(created_count=Sum('pax_number')))

print 'RESULTS: ', results
```

When I run my tests with Django's test runner: `python manage.py test`, I get the expected result:

```
RESULTS:  <QuerySet [{'created_count': 14, 'sd': datetime.date(2017, 2, 24)}]>
```

But when I do it with `pytest -s`, I get:

```
RESULTS:  <QuerySet [{'created_count': 14, 'sd': u'2017-02-24'}]>
```

Why isn't pytest converting dates like Django's test runner?

Comment: Have you tried `print type(results['sd'])`? Maybe `pytest` is simply changing the output for your convenience.

Comment: A quick test on my system using a hard-coded datetime.date just works as expected in both cases, so...  Is it the QuerySet or your environment that is strange?  Can you please try printing a hard-coded datetime.date instead of the QuerySet.

Comment: @intelis what is your DB configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the nice `datetime.date()` behaviour when I do the query against a postgresql database, but the `u'2017-02-24'` behaviour when running against a SQLLite database backend, so I expect that the problem is that for whatever reason when you are running with `pytest` you are using a different database backend from when you are running from `python manage.py test`.

#### Update (after a small bit of research)

SQLLite [does not have](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) a native date time data type, and can store date time values using TEXT, REAL or INTEGER data types. You then use the [date functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to display your date as you want.

In particular the `date()` SQLLite function **returns a string**, which is in fact equivalent to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ...)`. So I would expect the python library providing bindings to this also to return a string.

Normal SQL / postgresql however [does have native date time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html). And the `date()` function there returns a date object. So it makes sense that the python library handling these database types would return a `datetime.date` object too.

Comment: That would be my guess as well

Comment: Why does it depend on the DB backend? Any guesses?

Comment: @sureshvv because it depends on how they store dates in the database I think; see my update.